# Copying a file to sdcard

Tags: android, file, sd-card

I'm desperately trying to copy a file to the sdcard from my raw folder, but it won't work! The file just doesn't show up in the file manager, and the program I give the path to (via an intent) can't find it either. This is what I'm trying...

```
private void CopyAssets() throws IOException {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/jazz.pdf";
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jazz);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
    try {
       while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
          out.write(buff, 0, read);
       }
    } finally {
         in.close();

         out.close();
    }
}
```

After which I try...

```
    try {
        CopyAssets();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String aux = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/jazz.pdf";

    Uri path = Uri.parse(aux);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try {

        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        Toast.makeText(bgn1.this, "No Application Available to View PDF",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: have you given uses-permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Check permissions per @SadeshkumarPeriyasamy 's comment.  Also, try creating the output path by using `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/jazz.pdf"))`

Comment: @SadeshkumarPeriyasamy Yes, I have! In my android manifest: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @AleksG That's basically the same thing, but I tried it nevertheless, it still doesn't work... Could there be something wrong with my emulator? I really can't see what's wrong with this.

Comment: Also, after closing the output file, check whether it exists with `File.isFile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write `out.flush();` in finally block and let me know what happen,

```
finally {
       out.flush();
       in.close();
       out.close();
      }
```

**Update:**

Working code:

```
private void CopyAssets() throws IOException
{       
    InputStream myInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jazz);
    String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/jazz.pdf";
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
  }
}
```